# how to configure 4-port linux box for router

Tags: linux, networking, router

Please advise where I've gone wrong:

I have a new 4-port mini computer I want to use as a router (with usual services such as firewall, NAT, DNS) for my growing network.  Main reason is to take advantage of ipset in iptables and secondarily for better performance.  I have two digital switches plugged into eth0 and eth1 while the internet cable plugs into eth2.

I present the following config file settings and results.  From my desktop computer I can ssh into the new gateway box and from there I can ping a WAN address but not my local network addresses.  I've temporarily made iptables rather permissive to ensure it isn't the problem (or so I think).  I'm supposing there is a problem with dhcp based on syslog, but I don't know exactly what or how to fix it.

Thanks very much for taking the time to help!

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf listing (comment lines deleted for brevity):

```
ddns-update-style none;

option domain-name "ptj.lan";
option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 8.8.8.8; 

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

authoritative;

log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.10.101 192.168.10.254;
 option routers 192.168.10.60;
 option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;

 host tractorshed {
    hardware ethernet AC:CC:8E:0F:96:EC;
    fixed-address 192.168.10.22;
 }
 host screenporch {
    hardware ethernet AC:CC:8E:10:61:74;
    fixed-address 192.168.10.23;
 }
 host carport {
    hardware ethernet AC:CC:8E:10:61:6B;
    fixed-address 192.168.10.21;
 }
  host brotherprinter {
    hardware ethernet 00:1B:A9:15:65:70;
    fixed-address 192.168.10.10;
 }
   host nuc {
    hardware ethernet B8:AE:ED:7B:73:30;
    fixed-address 192.168.10.32;
 }
 host ptj-vision {
    hardware ethernet 4C:72:B9:21:0C:E4;
    fixed-address 192.168.10.31;
 }
}
```

/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server listing:

```
DHCPD_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

DHCPD_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid

INTERFACES="eth0 eth2 eth3"
# I know eth1 is labelled "4" on back of box so I'll use 4 for connection to a digital switch with address 192.168.10.60 so I can reach it
```

and  /etc/network/interfaces listing:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet dhcp

# and the static address interface (marked "4" on the box) which I'll use on LAN side for access to this machine:
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.10.60
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.10.255

#stuff to rebuild ipset and iptable on reboot:
pre-up ipset restore < /home/boss/BadIPLists/genblacklist.bak
pre-up ipset restore < /home/boss/BadIPLists/sshblacklist.bak
pre-up iptables-restore < /home/boss/iptables.rules
```

lastly, a sample from syslog:

```
Jan  8 14:59:54 debFirewall dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jan  8 14:59:54 debFirewall dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jan  8 15:04:43 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jan  8 15:04:50 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
Jan  8 15:05:05 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16
Jan  8 15:05:21 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jan  8 15:05:34 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jan  8 15:05:44 debFirewall dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jan  8 15:05:44 debFirewall dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jan  8 15:06:21 debFirewall kernel: [ 8422.877907] igb 0000:02:00.0 eth1: igb: eth1 NIC Link is Down
Jan  8 15:06:25 debFirewall kernel: [ 8427.224580] igb 0000:04:00.0 eth3: igb: eth3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
Jan  8 15:07:17 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jan  8 15:07:22 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jan  8 15:07:35 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jan  8 15:07:42 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jan  8 15:07:53 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jan  8 15:08:00 debFirewall dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18
Jan  8 15:08:10 debFirewall kernel: [ 8532.140374] igb 0000:04:00.0 eth3: igb: eth3 NIC Link is Down
Jan  8 15:08:18 debFirewall dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jan  8 15:08:18 debFirewall dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jan  8 15:08:19 debFirewall kernel: [ 8540.932948] igb 0000:02:00.0 eth1: igb: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

Comment: It’s working as expected, no? There would be no DHCP servers reachable on eth0 (yet another internal network) and eth3 (shouldn’t be connected?).

Comment: What do you mean by "digital switches"? If you can't ping your local addresses have you made sure their firewalls allow you to ping them? Do you get some IP configuration for your other interfaces besides eth1? Did you enable routing for your box? Have you configured your machine to use the box as a gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I learned that apparently connections to two NIC's can't communicate with each other even if the devices are on the same network (like 192.168.10.0).  There were some potential solutions but the best for me was to bridge them (eth0 eth1 and eth3) as explained here:
https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Also I had to enter the gateway address in /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf (option routers) so that dhcp clients would know where to send their packets.  The static addresses given in /etc/network/interfaces also need the gateway listing.

Now everything is working perfectly and my iptables/ipset configuration is blocking thousands of ip address attack vectors.